# Netbeans fails to build because the .jar file cannot be deleted

Tags: java, windows, cmd, build

Netbeans fails to build because .jar file from the previous build cannot be deleted. I am unable to delete the file manually or change/view its owners either even with Administrative Privileges. Is netbeans locking these files?

Comment: Its possible if you are currently running an instance. Maybe try shutting Netbeans down. Then go to task manager (For Windows) and end process the Netbeans IDE if it is still running in task manager

Comment: @SynchroDynamic I already tried that there are no instances of it running and netbeans also isn’t running. Even restarted the computer. Thank you for your response

Comment: What version of Netbeans are you using?

Comment: @SynchroDynamic 8.2

Comment: Can you edit your question and put the precise error in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I just had this problem. Netbeans isn't the real issue here. The problem is that Java SE is getting stuck for some odd reason. Windows has this problem with apps hanging in the background in general but it also could be the program not exiting correctly due to code.

Here's how I fixed it:
1) Closed NetBeans (may not actually be necessary though)
2) Opened task manager
3) Manually ended Netbeans processes if it's still hanging (again, may not be necessary)
4) Look for any process with "Java SE" in the name and end that process
5) Try to build again.

Worked for me.